hCaptcha and Borlabs cookies in WordPress
I have a wordpress with a contact form and I added hCaptcha to the form. With Borlabs Cookies 3.0 I block the form if the user don't accept all (including External media) in the cookie banner.
Instead of the form a consent box is showed and after the user accept the form is displayed including the field for the hCaptcha but without checkbox. Only refreshing the page or trying to submit the form makes the checkbox appear.
Steps to Reproduce:

Visit https://test.code-fish.eu/contact
When the cookie banner opens click on "Accept Only Essential cookies"
The Contact form and hCaptcha is blocked in Borlabs until the user clicks on "Unlock form and hCaptcha"
Click on "Unlock content" or "Accept required service and unblock content" the form is displayed and the hCaptcha field is
visible but empty:


In Borlabs I have a Service and a Content Blocker for that Service with the following in the "HTML" section:
<div class="brlbs-cmpnt-cb-preset-a">
    <p class="brlbs-cmpnt-cb-description">{{ description }}</p>
    <div class="brlbs-cmpnt-cb-buttons">
      <a class="brlbs-cmpnt-cb-btn" href="#" data-borlabs-cookie-unblock role="button">{{ unblockButton }}</a>
      <a class="brlbs-cmpnt-cb-btn" href="#" data-borlabs-cookie-accept-service role="button" style="display: {{ serviceConsentButtonDisplayValue }}">{{ acceptServiceUnblockContent }}</a>
    </div>
    <a class="brlbs-cmpnt-cb-provider-toggle" href="#" data-borlabs-cookie-show-provider-information role="button">{{ moreInformation }}</a>
</div>

I tried adding the following in the service Opt-in Code
<script src="https://js.hcaptcha.com/1/api.js?onload=hCaptchaOnLoad&render=explicit"></script>

I think I am missing something in the JavaScript section of the content blocker but I can't figure out what.
Any help would be highly appreciated!
